# Why is the sequence required to be convergent in Abel's Test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Recently I have learned Abel's Test for sequences, which states that:
if $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_n$$ converges, and $$y_1\geq y_2\geq...\geq0$$, then $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_ny_n$$ converges.

proof:
From the summation by parts, $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_ny_n=\sum^\infty_{n=1}s_n(y_n-y_{n+1})+s_ny_{n+1}$$
where $s_n=x_1+x_2+...+x_n$

since $s_k$ converges, it is bounded, then $\exists M\geq |s_n|\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

thus $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}s_n(y_n-y_{n+1})\leq M\sum^\infty_{n=1}(y_n-y_{n+1})=M(y_1-\lim{y_n})$$

thus $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}x_ny_n$$ converges by the Comparison Test.

---

But I notice that $s_k$ here does not necessarily need to be convergent, the statement also holds if $s_k$ is bounded.

Then it also gives me some confusion in understanding Dirichlet's Test, because if Abel's Test also holds if $s_k$ is bounded, then the statement is the same as Dirichlet's Test, and I also cannot find out the reason why $\lim b_n\to 0$ is required in Dirichlet's Test. [Dirichlet's Test]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: There's still the $s_ny_{n+1}$-term to consider. It may not converge if $s_n$ doesn't converge.

Comment: You recover the Dirichlet test if $y_n\to 0$, then the $s_n y_{n+1}$ term in the equation $\sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k = \sum_{k=1}^n s_k (y_k-y_{k+1}) + s_n y_{n+1}$ will vanish as $n\to\infty$ and you can apply the proof you have indicated. With neither $y_n\to0$ or $s_n$ convergent the series $\sum_k x_k y_k$ will not converge, as the $s_n y_{n+1}$ term does not converge but the $\sum_{k=1}^ns_k( y_k-y_{k+1})$ term does.

Comment: Thank you I got it.